# strtoupper() doesn't work with bloginfo() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, capitalization

How are you, this is very weird thing I got today.

```
<?php echo bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> // this return How Are You
<?php echo strtoupper(bloginfo( 'name' )); ?> // this also return How Are You
<?php echo strtoupper( 'How Are You' ); ?> //this return HOW ARE YOU
```

I think second should return HOW ARE YOU, it's very weird.
I am not sure the reason of this thing.

Comment: Have you checked the type of `bloginfo('name')` to be sure it is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `bloginfo( 'name' )` directly prints result into a browser, it doesn't return it.

To get a value, use [get_bloginfo()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much